# Direct bus options from San Antonio, TX to Monterrey, NL Mexico?

Tags: buses, mexico, texas

Are there any nonstop or faster bus options from San Antonio, TX to Monterrey, NL Mexico? There's Greyhound but they stop at both Laredo and Nuevo Laredo, increasing the travel time significantly.

Comment: Why do you think that stopping in Laredo and Nuevo Laredo significantly adds to the trip duration.  Greyhounds website says about 30 minutes at Laredo and zero time in Nuevo Laredo for the stop duration.

Comment: Not sure, but Google maps estimates the drive is 5hr while Greyhound's schedule somehow takes 6:45.

Comment: Google maps is showing 1:30 approx in Laredo, but I'm seeing different stop times for different departure times. Check on Greyhound's site rather than Google Maps.

Comment: Bus schedules are always going to take longer than a google estimated time.  This has nothing to do with this particular route.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, no.  Bear in mind border crossings may require a change of bus, or at the least, a delay while an entire bus goes through passport control.  That takes a lot longer than one car load, so it's not entirely fair to compare the two.

[Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/map/San-Antonio/Monterrey) shows 3 options for bus, ranging from 6h47 to 11h21.